# Why is multiprocessing with Queue hanging?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to explore the use of the `multiprocessing` module with the help of [this guide](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-multiprocessing-queue/).

It suggests running this code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def addPositive(queue):
    print("I am in addPositive.")
    for i in range(1, 100):
        queue.put(i)

def addNegative(queue):
    print("I am in addNegative.")
    for i in range(-100, 0):
        queue.put(i)

myQueue = mp.Queue()
process1 = mp.Process(target=addPositive, args=(myQueue,))
process2 = mp.Process(target=addNegative, args=(myQueue,))
process1.start()
process2.start()
process1.join()
process2.join()
while myQueue:
    print(myQueue.get(), end=",")
myQueue.close()
```

Running this code I get a `Runtime` error which I think is caused by the lack of a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. I've updated the code to:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def addPositive(queue):
    print("I am in addPositive.")
    for i in range(1, 100):
        queue.put(i)


def addNegative(queue):
    print("I am in addNegative.")
    for i in range(-100, 0):
        queue.put(i)


def run():
    myQueue = mp.Queue()
    process1 = mp.Process(target=addPositive, args=(myQueue,))
    process2 = mp.Process(target=addNegative, args=(myQueue,))
    process1.start()
    process2.start()
    process1.join()
    process2.join()
    while myQueue:
        print(myQueue.get(), end=",")
    myQueue.close()

 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

When I run this I get the two `print` statements from the two functions but then the execution hangs and does nothing else.

The output I'm expecting after that should look something like:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,-1001,11,12,13,-1000,-999,-998,-997,-996,-995,-994,-993,-992,-991,-990,-989,-988,-987,-986,-985,-984,-983,-982,-981,14,-980,15,-979,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,-978,-977,-976,-975,-974,-973,-972,-971,-970...
```

Could someone help out with what's going wrong?

- Python: 3.9.6
- OS: macOS Monterey 12.4

Comment: Did you mean: `while myQueue.qsize():`?

Comment: Hi. Tried your change and get a `NotImplementedError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your queue exists, `while myQueue:` will run forever and never exit.

As quamrana suggests, normally using `myQueue.qsize()` in the while-loop should fix the problem.
But as the documentation states, this doesn't exist on macOS.
So try `while not myQueue.empty():` instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Tried the change and get a `NotImplementedError`.

Comment: @Jossy See updated answer.

Comment: That did the trick - thanks!